# How do I properly dereference an object to set it's member variable in the following case?

Tags: c++

I'm implementing a tree by writing a class called `Node`, and I'm having issues concerning the following method and member variables:

```
class Node {
public:
    // ...
    void addChild(const std::shared_ptr<Node> node);
private:
    // ...
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node> > _children;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> _parent;
};
```

When `addChild` is called by a `Node` object, it's simply supposed to set the argument's `_parent` member to point to the caller, then add the argument to the caller's vector of children. My implementation currently looks like this:

```
void Node::addChild(const std::shared_ptr<Node> node) {
    if (!node) {
        std::invalid_argument("Argument node must be nonnull.");
    }

    *node._parent = this;
    _children.push_back(node);
}
```

The troublesome line is `*node._parent = this;`, which causes this error:

```
src/Node.cpp:89:10: error: no member named '_parent' in
'std::__1::shared_ptr<Node>'; did you mean to use '->' instead of '.'?
```

My train of thinking is telling me that I'm dereferencing `node` to gain access to the actual `Node` object, then using `._parent` to gain access to the `_parent` member. Since `_parent` is a `std::shared_ptr<Node>`, it would then make sense to set it to equal `this`, which is a pointer to the calling object. But why is my compiler telling me that `_parent` doesn't exist when it definitely does exist?

Edit: I've also already attempted `(*node)._parent`, `node->_parent`, `(*node)->_parent`, and `*(*node)._parent`, all to no avail. They all result in `error: no viable overloaded '='`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line of code: `*node._parent = this;` has two issues:

1. operator precedence
2. assignment to `shared_ptr`

First operator precedence. Operator `.` is evaluated before operator `*`. So  currently your code is similar to doing this:

```
*(node._parent)
```

`node` doesn't have a `_parent` member, but `*node` does. So, fix it by either:

```
(*node)._parent
```

Or even better:

```
node->_parent
```

Then, you have another issue that you can't just assign to `shared_ptr` with `operator =()` like this. You need to change

```
= this;
```

To:

```
.reset(this);
```

So in total,

```
node->_parent.reset(this);
```

Comment: I've tried both already, and they both result in `error: no viable overloaded '='`. I was actually in the middle of making an edit to express that.

Comment: Worked beautifully. I wasn't aware `.reset()` could be used like that. This project is my first serious usage of C++11 pointers, so I'm still learning the idiosyncrasies of them.